# How do I show a list of variables and their associated values as a list or table?

Tags: output-formatting, formatting

I would like to do calculations using various variables as inputs along with functions or formulas and once all variables are calculated I need to output some or all of them in a table (or list).

Here is a simple example

```
c = 3*10^8
Zo = 100
\[Epsilon]r = 2.2
d = 0.762*10^-3
f = 2.5*10^9
A = Zo/60 Sqrt[(\!\(TraditionalForm\`\(TraditionalForm\`\[Epsilon]r\)\
\) + 1)/2] + (\!\(TraditionalForm\`\(TraditionalForm\`\[Epsilon]r\)\) \
- 1)/(\!\(TraditionalForm\`\(TraditionalForm\`\[Epsilon]r\)\) + 
    1) (0.23 + 0.11/\[Epsilon]r)
W = d (8 E^A)/(E^(2 A) - 2)
\!\(TraditionalForm\`\[Epsilon]ff\) = \
(\!\(TraditionalForm\`\(TraditionalForm\`\[Epsilon]r\)\) + 1)/
  2 + (\!\(TraditionalForm\`\(TraditionalForm\`\[Epsilon]r\)\) - 1)/
   2 (1 + 12 d/W)^(-(1/2))
\[Lambda] = c/f 1/Sqrt[\!\(TraditionalForm\`\[Epsilon]ff\)]
```

And all I want to do is output the list of variables and their calculated values in a list or table.

Answer (score 5):

I hacked out this two-liner based on some other entries and it is what I'm looking for. Thanks for the help and insights

```
Vars = Select[Names["Global`*"], 
   Head@Symbol[#] =!= Symbol && Head@Symbol[#] =!= Function &];
Transpose@{Transpose@ {Vars}, 
   Transpose@ {ToExpression@Vars}} // TableForm
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit funky, but...

If you define a function for `$NewSymbol`, it will execute every time a new symbol is defined. You could use this to collect all symbols that get created in the Global` context (assuming that's the context you will be working in).

But first, let's define a variable/structure to hold this data.

```
SymbolMap = <||>
```

Now let's define our collector.

```
$NewSymbol = If["Global`" === #2, AssociateTo[SymbolMap, #1 -> Symbol[#1]]] &
```

If we now execute the code from the original post, we should see that those symbols have been collected.

```
SymbolMap
(* output: 
  <|"c" -> c, "Zo" -> Zo, "\[Epsilon]r" -> \[Epsilon]r, "d" -> d, "f" -> f, "A" -> A, "W" -> W, "\[Epsilon]ff" -> \[Epsilon]ff, "\[Lambda]" -> \[Lambda]|> *)
```

When we're ready, we can select those that evaluate to a value (assuming you don't want things like functions with DownValues)

```
Select[SymbolMap, ValueQ]
```

Now, you said you wanted a list or table that shows the values. Here are some options:

```
Normal[Select[SymbolMap, ValueQ]]
(* output: 
  {"c" -> 300000000, "Zo" -> 100, "\[Epsilon]r" -> 2.2, "d" -> 0.000762, "f" -> 2.5*10^9, "A" -> 1.91569, "W" -> 0.000938264, "\[Epsilon]ff" -> 1.78304, "\[Lambda]" -> 0.0898672}*)


KeyValueMap[List, Select[SymbolMap, ValueQ]] // TableForm
(* outputs tabular view of above *)
```

Answer (score 2):

You mean like this?

```
{{"c", "Zo", "εr", "d", "f", "A", "W", "εff", 
   "λ"}, {c, Zo, εr, d, f, A, 
   W, εff, λ}} // TableForm
```

> [image: tab]

Edit: a small improvement:

Start by defining a list of names and a list of numbers

```
names = {"c", "Zo", "εr", "d", "f", "A", "W", 
   "εff", "λ"};
values = {c, Zo, λr, d, f, A, 
   W, εff, λ};
```

Before you assign any numerical values [`TableForm`] returns the plain symbols

```
TableForm@{names, values}
```

> [image: tabb]

Now, we run the code from the OP and we get names and numbers

```
TableForm@{names, values}
```

> [image: tabbb]

Comment: Yes, something like that works. Is there a way to generate those two lists automatically based on the variable space instead of typing them out manually by hand?

I can use something like this 

Names["Global`*"]
Var = Select[Names["Global`*"], 
  Head@Symbol[#] =!= Symbol && Head@Symbol[#] =!= Function &]

to generate the list of variables, but I don't know how to extract the name/values out in a reproducable way

Comment: @SteveMaher I don't understand what you mean when you say `variable space`. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I edited my comment above. By variable space, i just meant all the variables that I define or use in the cell or notebook.

Comment: @SteveMaher well, I updated with sort of an improvement in the sense that you define two lists in the beginning and that's it. Then, every time you display you get the numerical values and the names. Not sure if that's what you want exactly. I think you want even more automatic